# How to handle Enter key in Win32 multiline Edit control?

Tags: c++, winapi, multiline

I have a multiline Edit control that allow to multiline text from other source (i.e copy/paste,...) but I don't want to allow user have new line by press Enter key directly.
How can I handle Enter key in this case? Thank!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a simple sub-class of the edit control that blocks the return key:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK EditSubclassProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    if (uMsg == WM_CHAR && wParam == VK_RETURN)
        return 0;
    LRESULT lRes = DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    if (uMsg == WM_DESTROY)
        RemoveWindowSubclass(hWnd, EditSubclassProc, 0);
    return lRes;
}
```

To invoke it:

```
SetWindowSubclass(hWndEdit, EditSubclassProc, 0, 0);
```